# Extend child component props into wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a wrapper component that picks the partial of some props of an inner component and adds some custome defined props. The problem with this is that pick will create a type not an interface. so I'm unable to add other keys. How can I perform this?

```
type innerProps = Partial<Pick<InnerComponentProps<T>, |"id"|"otherProps">>
interface outerComponentProps {
    // extend inner props and add more custom props
}
```

Is there a way to "destructure" `innerProps` into `outerComponentProps`?

Comment: `type outerComponentProps = innerProps & { additionalProp: string }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a few ways, but to stick with interfaces, you could extend the `Partial<Pick<InnerComponentProps, 'id'|'otherProps'>>` type:

```js
interface InnerComponentProps {
    id: number;
    otherProps: object[];
    skippedProp: boolean;
}

interface OuterComponentProps extends 
  Partial<Pick<InnerComponentProps, 'id' | 'otherProps'>> 
{
    newProp: string;
}
```

[Typescript-playground demo](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhNAwgewLYAOOm4AClDgQM4A8AKgHzIDeAUMh8sACYBcyIAK54ARtADc7TjjAALaOUpV+dANoBdSZ2RUA1sAIEI3RQRWSAvq1ahIsRCgDygu7kLEIZCtXpMIAD0gQbipkUjgoMGA4ABsaUmAEXRp0TCg3IhIwU1pGABpkAHIeQuQAHyKZeSgcwoYmNm1MAHdTfiowKFAAc0trMABPI2R-ZABeZGdXfEzPbO9aERwcGIg4EAZJAHot5ABZOAJkORRB4aocZGaUBHXkWRwAN2hkJ5fCgdL17h0IU-lkARvNAohAqKwzigBuMWMhVLoINDQMgEQMcDARup+P54Yj1BZxEA)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that interfaces can extend types.